# Enabling Rtree on sqlite3 python module

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, sqlite

Trying to run the following code:

```
conn.executescript("""
            CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE Hashes USING rtree(
```

gives the following error:sqlite3 operational error no such module: rtree

To fix this, I have built the windows dll from the sqlite source with rtrees enabled.

Where should i put the dll in order for the sqlite3 python module to recognize it?

Is there any other fix for enabling rtree module on sqlite3 python module?

python version 2.7

Comment: Wherever you find the old DLL. But it might be possible that your Python has the SQLite compiled into its own executable.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this should be copied into the Dlls directory

[image: Example directory structure]